# Angular 2 - List of events

Tags: events, angular

I'm newbie to Angular 2. What are the corresponding events from AngularJS to Angular 2?
eg: `ng-click` to (click)

How about `ng-init` and all others events? I'm not having intellisense in VS .NET, so it's hard to guess.

Any help please!

Thanks

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The default handled events should be mapped from the original HTML DOM component's events:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

by just removing the `on` prefix.

`onclick` ---> `(click)`

`onkeypress` ---> `(keypress)`

etc...

You can also create your custom events.

However `ngInit` is not an HTML event, this is part of the Angular's Component lifecycle, and in Angular 2 they are handled using "hooks", which are basically specific method names inside your component that will be called whenever the component enters the specific cycle. Like:

[ngOnInit](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnInit-interface.html#!#sts=ngOnInit())

[ngOnDestroy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnDestroy-interface.html#!#sts=ngOnDestroy())

etc...

Comment: "The default handled events should be mapped from the original HTML DOM component's events" <- Can you please quote your source, or provide a list of available events? I could not find any official Angular 2 list of events.

Comment: Here's a [more complete](http://www.w3fools.com/) list of [DOM Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Comment: Here is another place to chekc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: @Langley Do you have the link to a full list of Angular specific events, such as `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy`?

Comment: wow, the most popular answer is not so accurate after all,it can be misleading to lot of users, so let me explain what i mean, onclick is a javascript dom event, where as click is a original html dom event. So, it is not exactly onclick --> click, it is simply click -> (click)

Answer (score 18):

Here is the list of events in Angular 
Please check in the documentation if required for more info

```
(focus)="myMethod()"
(blur)="myMethod()" 
(submit)="myMethod()"  
(scroll)="myMethod()"

(cut)="myMethod()"
(copy)="myMethod()"
(paste)="myMethod()"

(keydown)="myMethod()"
(keypress)="myMethod()"
(keyup)="myMethod()"

(mouseenter)="myMethod()"
(mousedown)="myMethod()"
(mouseup)="myMethod()"

(click)="myMethod()"
(dblclick)="myMethod()"

(drag)="myMethod()"
(dragover)="myMethod()"
(drop)="myMethod()"
```

Comment: Where is this list from? What documentation do you mean?

Comment: @BillyTom documentation link is: https://www.positronx.io/useful-list-of-angular-7-event-types-for-event-binding/

Comment: Actually there are many many more. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Answer (score 6):

This is one of the big advantages of Angular2. Not every event needs a customized `ng-xxx` directive anymore.
With custom elements and all other libraries producing all kinds of custom events, this approach doesn't fly.

In Angular2 the `(eventName)="expression"` binding syntax allows to subscribe to any known and unknown event.

The `$event` variable is still available `(eventName)="myEventHandler($event)"`

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding

Comment: what type is $event of? Instead of putting any in the .ts file which is the predefined event for it?

Comment: That depends on `eventName`. For DOM events you get the information from mdn (like ’click` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) and if it's from an Angular directive or component you get it from its documentation.

Answer (score 2):

A great place to begin to understand Angular 2 is the official Web Page.

[Here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/) you can see all the **angular2/common** ng-XXX although now it is as follows **ngXxxx**

[image]

In my case the best way to understand the differences between Angular 1 and Angular 2 was doing the tutorials:

- [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)
- [The Developer Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/): this is a practical guide to Angular for experienced programmers who are building client applications in HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax to handle events (for example `click` like `ng-click` with Angular1):

```
<button (click)="callSomeMethodOfTheComponent()">Click</button>
```

The difference here is that this is more generic. I mean you can use DOM events directly but also custom ones defined using the `EventEmitter` class.

Here is a sample that describes how to handle a `click` event and a custom event (`my-event`) trigged by a sub component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="callSomeMethodOfTheComponent()">Click</button>
      <sub-component (my-event)="callSomeMethodOfTheComponent()"></sub-component>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [SubComponent]
})
export class MyComponent {
  callSomeMethodOfTheComponent() {
    console.log('callSomeMethodOfTheComponent called');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'sub-component',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="myEvent.emit()">Click (from sub component)</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class SubComponent {
  @Output()
  myEvent: EventEmitter;

  constructor() {
    this.myEvent = new EventEmitter();
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry